# Windows Phone Visibility Behaviours in CPU

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, visibility, cpu-usage

I'd like to ask how objects behave in our phone when we program our applications.

Assume that we have some ellipses, squares rotating around a point, that is, there is a graphic animations where all animation is supposed to be an object as XAML.

If we make this animation Visibility="Collapsed"; what will phone CPU do? Does it still work in CPU without displaying on the screen, or it throws into suspended state into harddrive or something, or in other words, any visibility collapsed object including button, webpage, animations etc. consume the CPU and hence, the battery just as it does while visibility="visible"?

Thanks for your enlightening me in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to  hide objects on the screen

**Visibility Property**

When the `Visibility` property is set to `Collapsed`, XAML does not hold any visual data for the element in visual memory and does not do any processing related to the element. 
Setting `Visibility` to `Visible`, will draw the contents of the visual tree and the element is completely.

**Opacity**
You can improve performance in your app by manipulating the `Opacity` property of elements when you are using bitmap caching. Bitmap caching allows visual elements to be stored as bitmaps after the first render pass. After the element is cached, the app bypasses the render phase for the cached visual element and displays the stored bitmap instead. When you set the Opacity for a cached element to 0, a bitmap representation of the element is saved in memory.  It's recommanded to use BitmapCaching (set `CacheMode` property to  `BitmapCache`) in scenarios where you are blending, transforming (translating, stretching, rotating).

WP supports a composition thread in addition to the UI thread. UI thread will parse and create objects from XAML, Draw all visuals the first time they are drawn and Process per-frame callbacks and execute other user code. Composition thread combines graphics textures and passes them to the GPU for drawing. There are also some optimisatins forstoryboard-driven animations.

Maintaining a lightweight UI thread is the key to writing a responsive app.